# Microsoft Teams webhook send image

Tags: microsoft-teams

I want to send image (saved as base64 table) via webhook to my Teams channel.
When i use adaptiveCards it is small and there is no way to open it with real size. Is there a way to show that image in the same way as when i upload image by myself (small picture is shown, but when i point it there is clicable hand icon that opens full size image)?

```
    {
  "@type": "MessageCard",
  "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
  "summary": "New Image",
  "themeColor": "0076D7",
  "sections": [
    {
      "activityTitle": "New Image",
      "activitySubtitle": "A new image has been uploaded",
      "activityImage": "https://example.com/full_size_image.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you